# Coin tossing questions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had an exam today and I would like to know for sure that I got these answers correct.

A fair coin will be tossed repeatedly.

1. What is the probability that in 5 flips we will obtain exactly 4 heads.
2. Let $X =$ # flips until we have obtained the first head. Find the conditional probability of $P(X=4|X\geq2)$.
3. What is the probability that the fifth heads will occur on the sixth flip?

Here are my answers:

1. $\frac{5}{32}$
2. $\frac{1}{8}$
3. $\frac{5}{64}$

Comment: Looks good. (Did you notice that (1) already did half of the work for (3)?)

Comment: Numbers are correct.

Comment: I got the same answer for 1 and 3 but different for 2. I got 1/16.

Comment: Yep noticed that, but not in the exam hehe.

Comment: @Scorpio: You need the probability the sequence starts TTTH... given that the sequence starts T......

Comment: @Henry Yes, you are right. I did not notice that thing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the general consensus is that you are right.